# Add String Into Another String After Certain String in Java

Tags: java

This is all an example of what I'd like to do

```
String text = "<%1$s> %2$s"
String otherText = "HELLO"
```

```
Output: <%1$sHELLO> %2$s
```

How could I add otherText after the certain string `<%$s`???

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure on how to split the string after <%$s and then add otherText, then combine it back together.

Comment: no need to split get the index of `<%$s` from the string then add `ind=indexFound+"<%$s".length()` then use the loop to iterate over the `text` if    `ind` is found add `HELLO` else normal concatenation of `text` char by char. I have tried code but it is not good if I will give you direct code as you have to try something first to learn .

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand what to do.

Comment: http://ideone.com/diN7FL

Comment: If `pos` is the position where you want to insert `otherText` you can just write `text.substring(0, pos) + otherText + text.substring(pos)`

Comment: Thankyou singhakash, it's exactly what i needed.

Comment: @singhakash your solution is much to complicated...

Answer (score 0):

A `StringBuilder` in this case would be very helpful. It has an `insert` method which is exactly what you need.

All the code in this post assumes that `text` and `otherText` is defined as the OP has stated.

First, create a `StringBuilder`

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder (text);
```

And then call `insert`:

```
builder.insert (5, otherText);
```

Now you're done. You can store this string in a variable by calling `toString()`.

```
String finalString = builder.toString();
```

For more information, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#insert(int,%20java.lang.String)

Here are some examples on how to use `insert`:

```
"12345" -> insert(1, "a") -> "1a2345"
"12345" -> insert(2, "a") -> "12a345"
"12345" -> insert(0, "x") -> "x12345"
"12345" -> insert(10, "y") -> exception!
```